# How can I send a matrix with pipe() between parent process and child process?

Tags: c, linux, multiprocessing, pipe, ipc

I declared and allocated matrix like this :

```
int** prevMatrix = NULL;

prevMatrix = (int**)malloc(sizeof(int*) * (arraySize[0] + 2));
for (int i = 0; i < arraySize[0] + 2; i++)
    prevMatrix[i] = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * (arraySize[1] + 2));
```

And I want to know how can I send this matrix from child process to parent process.
I tried to using pipe(), but I think I put a wrong value in write() buffer size.

How can I send this matrix to parent process?

Comment: `sizeof(int*) * arraySize[0] + 2` __is not__ `sizeof(int*) * (arraySize[0] + 2)`. Your allocation is invalid.

Comment: @KamilCuk oh, I missed while copying here. I wrote the code like yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the best examples why sometimes it's better to not allocate a double pointer, but to allocate a single one and do some simple arithmetic to get the index.

Say you need a matrix `m` with dimensions `x` and `y`. Allocation would be:

```
int *m = malloc(x * y * sizeof *m);
```

Accessing an element at index (i, j) would be:

```
m[i * x + j]
```

Sending the values over a socket `fd`:

```
send(fd, m, x * y, 0);
```

Or:

```
write(fd, m, x * y);
```

The alternative is to keep using a multidimensional matrix, but then you would have to send row-by-row, which is much more of a nuisance.

Comment: I didn't think of a way to solve it like this. Thank you for your time!